# How do I make the Form disappear when a button is clicked?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to make a button which forwards me to the Print Preview page in Excel.

The annoying thing is, that the form with the button will stay open and I am also unable to interact with it directly (I can close the whole thing). So I can't move it out of the way to look at the preview or press any other button on the form.

I have already tried the `.hide` and `.visible=false` but neither of them worked. It spits out errors or won't make a difference at all.

```
Private Sub Drucken_IST_Click()

  Worksheets("Bestand").PrintOut Preview:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: "It spits out errors"... what errors?  Have you tried `.PrintPreview EnableChanges:=True`

Comment: You can also just hide the form using `Me.Hide`.

Comment: You can also use the `UserForm1.Show vbModeless` method. This will allow you to continue to interact with Excel while the userform is up. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/show-method

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to unload the form?
Here is an example of how to do it. Let me know if it works! :)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Unload YourForm1 ' unload
Sheets("YourSheet").Select
YourForm1.Show
End Sub
```